# Keyup issue with escape-code input

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am writing a page to take information out of a database table and place it into an HTML table.  I am then using jQuery to make any `<td>` cell editable upon being clicked on and am now trying to use the jQuery keyup function to detect when the editable cell has been edited and then use ajax to update the database with the edited information. keyup is picking up when numbers, letters, and the space bar are pressed but for some reason it is not picking up when the backspace, delete, or enter keys are being pressed. I am not sure if I have an error in my code or what could be causing this.

Any comments or suggestions would be extremely helpful, thank you very much!

Here is the jQuery I am using for the click event and then also for keyup along with a quick table example:

```js
$('td').click(function() {
  var val = ($(this).siblings().first().text());
  var col = $(this).parent().children().index($(this));

  $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);

  $(this).keyup(function() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "updatedatabase.php",
        data: {
          content: $(this).text(),
          date: val
        }
      })
      .done(function(msg) {
        alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
      });
  });
});
```

```css
table, th, td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  font-size: 90%;
}
th, td {
  padding: 8px;
}
td {
  text-align: center;
}
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
}
td:click {
  background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th></th>
    <th>22oz Dark</th>
    <th>12ct 4oz Dark</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-01</th>
    <td>9785</td>
    <td>2478</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-02</th>
    <td>8754</td>
    <td>2136</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-03</th>
    <td>13587</td>
    <td>2203</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-04</th>
    <td>14111</td>
    <td>3297</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-05</th>
    <td>13212</td>
    <td>3101</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-06</th>
    <td>16335</td>
    <td>3299</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>2016-01-07</th>
    <td>15421</td>
    <td>3100</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You want to call ajax  when enter key is pressed??

Comment: Ok so let me try to explain a different way.  The HTML table contains a production schedule, the schedule can be edited by clicking on a cell and then typing the new count to be ran in the cell.  I want to write the new data into the database as soon as the data is modified in any way.  (I cant trust the guys to click out of the cell or anything like that.)  It works if a new value is placed in the cell currently, but not if information is deleted out and the cell left blank.  I guess the enter key isnt important, just something I noticed trying to test it out.

Comment: Attaching an event handler within another event handler is in most cases wrong. Imagine if you click on that `td` twice: you'll have just doubled the traffic to your server when starting to type.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pick up changes, you could find the `input` event useful: it triggers even on changes that are made via the mouse or context menu (think copy/paste, ...etc).

You should also definitely take out the inner event handler from the outer event handler. As you have it now, you'll accumulate the number of `keyup` event handlers every time you click on the same `td` element.

Also, I don't think you want users to change the first column, as it contains the key you send to the server.

So here is what I suggest:

```
// exclude first column from jQuery selection:
$('td').not(':first').click(function() {
  $(this).prop('contenteditable', true);
});

// Use input event, and define it outside of above event handler:
$('td').on('input', function() {
  console.log('event');
  $.ajax({
    method: "POST",
    url: "updatedatabase.php",
    data: {
      content: $(this).text(),
      date: $(this).siblings().first().text() // calculate on-the-spot
    }
  })
  .done(function(msg) {
    alert("Data Saved: " + msg);
  });
});
```

Unrelated to your question: you make the content editable when the user clicks on a cell. You never make it uneditable afterwards, so one could wonder why you don't make them all editable from the start...

Comment: Using on instead of keyup works great!  As far as making all editable, is there a plus or minus to doing this?

Comment: If the `td` elements are editable from the start, you only need to click once to put your cursor in them, otherwise you need to click twice the first time you want to edit content in a specific `td`.