# Create list dynamically from array javascript

Tags: javascript, html, arrays

I need to create a list from an array. 
I pass an input value and recreate the list with all the matches I found.
if there's no match I need to show the "no results" message.

- inputValue = "Ja" returns Jack and Jake
- inputValue = "Jak" returns Jake
- inputValue = "foo" returns "No results"

```js
var arr = [{"name": "Jack"}, {"name": "Jake"}];
var txtName = document.querySelector("#txtName");

txtName.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
  arr.forEach(function(item){
    if(item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(txtName.value) > -1){
        myList.innerHTML +=
        `<li>${item.name}</li>`
        return
      }else{
        myList.innerHTML = `<li>No results </li>`
      }
  });
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtName">
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```

Comment: What is your problem and your question? Can't believe someone up voted this question.

Comment: also checkout "CSS :empty" it would be more elegant and flexible... ex:https://coderwall.com/p/k7httg/elegant-empty-lists

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should only decide to output "No results" at the end of the loop. You cannot know whether it is appropriate to output this at some arbitrary iteration of the loop, so you are wiping out good results that might already have been output.

Here is a corrected version:

```js
var arr = [{"name": "Jack"}, {"name": "Jake"}];
var txtName = document.querySelector("#txtName");

txtName.addEventListener('keyup', function(e){
    var lowText = txtName.value.toLowerCase();
    var matches = arr.filter(function(item){
        return item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(lowText) > -1;
    }).map(function (item) {
        return `<li>${item.name}</li>`;
    }).join('');
    myList.innerHTML = matches || `<li>No results </li>`;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtName">
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```

If you want an empty input to give "No results" instead of all items, then change the definition of `matches` to:

```
var matches = lowText.length && arr.filter( // ...etc
```

Comment: Empty value returns all results - not sure if that is desired or not. Should confirm with OP

Comment: @mhodges, good remark. I just added a variant, so the OP can choose.

Comment: @jsilva13 See Scott Marcus' solution and my comment on why to use `input` instead of `keyup`

Comment: @mhodges, yes, I also keep saying that, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40268352/keyup-issue-with-escape-code-input/40269139#40269139), but for some reason people keep using `keyup`. This time I thought to just leave it, and focus on the essence of the question. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Don't write to `.innerHTML` more than you need to. It causes the DOM to update and you should only do that when you have to. Instead, build up a string and then inject the string once it's complete. In your case, you are writing "No Results" if one particular iteration of the loop doesn't find a match, but other iterations might, so only write "no results" after you know there weren't any. You can use a simple flag variable to keep track of whether matches were found.

Clear the results as you write new data and know that you can't `return` from a `.forEach()`

Also, if you are going to convert one string to lower case, you need to also convert the other so that you are comparing lower to lower.

And, change `keyup` to `input` so that it will work on devices that don't support keyboard events (i.e. mobile devices), .

```js
var arr = [{name: "Jack"}, {name: "Jake"}];
var txtName = document.getElementById("txtName");

txtName.addEventListener('input', function(e){
  myList.innerHTML = "";  // Clear out old results
  
  var output = "";            // This will be the results
  var foundItems = false;     // "Flag" that keeps track of whether matches were found
  
  // You can't return from a .forEach loop
  arr.forEach(function(item){

    // Compare lower case against lower case
    if(item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(txtName.value.toLowerCase()) > -1){
         output += `<li>${item.name}</li>`
         foundItems = true;   // Set flag
    }
  });
  
  // Check flag
  if(foundItems){
    myList.innerHTML = output;  // Flag is up, use found data
  } else {
    // Flag is still down, no results
    myList.innerHTML = `<li>No results </li>`;
  }
});
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtName">
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```

Comment: `input` also handles right click cut/paste operations, which is a big difference many people miss or don't know about.

Comment: @mhodges Yes. Overall, I think it's a much better choice unless you want to prevent some input from ever even making it into the element in the first place, then `keydown` is the way to go.

Comment: I really forgot the lowerCase on the input value. And the input event is really great to know.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a container for your results(in the snippet it's a div called myResults) then repopulate the container when text is entered.

I'm not sure what type of functionality you wanted when it comes to matching. Currently it'll match if `a` is entered in since `Jack` and `Jake` both contain `a`. However, if nothing is found it will display that result.

The way this works is that we have a function that creates a new list every time something is entered into the box. It determines if any of the names include the text box value, if they do it appends them as list items to the list. At the end of the function it uses the `childElementCount` property to determine if any list items were added. If they weren't we know nothing matched, and we set the text to `No Results Found`.

```js
var arr = [{
  "name": "Jack"
}, {
  "name": "Jake"
}];
var txtName = document.querySelector("#txtName"),
  results = document.querySelector("#myResults");

txtName.addEventListener('keyup', function(e) {
  results.innerHTML = "";
  results.appendChild(createList(this.value));
});

function createList(value) {
  let create = (tag, props = {}) => Object.assign(document.createElement(tag), props),
    appendTo = (p, c) => {
      if (p) p.appendChild(c);
      return p;
    },

    list = create("ul");
    list.id = "myList";
  for (let value_obj of arr) {
    if (value_obj.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(value.toLowerCase()) > -1) {
      appendTo(list, create("li", {
        textContent: value_obj.name
      }));
    }
  }
  if(list.childElementCount == 0) list.textContent = "No Results Found";
  return list;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtName">
<div id="myResults"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to clear/rewrite the html for your list for every event. Then filter down your results to a matching set, if no match is found end the event while adding your no result item this stops processing on empty results or no match. Only iterate if you have matches, so save that bit for after your empty check.

```js
const arr = [{"name": "Jack"}, {"name": "Jake"}];
const txtName = document.querySelector("#txtName");
const myList = document.querySelector('#myList');

const findName = e => {
  myList.innerHTML = "";
  const matches = arr.filter(val => val.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(e.target.value) > -1);

  if (matches.length === 0 || e.target.value == '') {
    myList.innerHTML = '<li>No Results</li>';
    return;
  }
  matches.forEach(val => {
    let current = document.createElement('li')
    current.textContent = val.name;
    myList.appendChild(current);
  });
}

txtName.addEventListener('keyup', findName);
```

```html
<input type="text" id="txtName">
<ul id="myList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="text" id="txtName" onkeyup="filter(this.value)">
<ul id="myList"></ul>   

<script type="text/javascript">
var arr = [{
  "name": "Jack"
}, {
  "name": "Jake"
}];
var txtName = document.querySelector("#txtName");

var filter = function(val) {
  var regex = new RegExp("^" + val, "i");
  var result = arr.filter(function(obj) {
    return obj.name.search(regex) > -1;
  });

  if (result.length == 0) {
    myList.innerHTML = 'No results';
  } else {
    myList.innerHTML = '';
    result.forEach(function(item) {
      myList.innerHTML += `<li>${item.name}</li>`;
    });
  }
}
</script>
```